# Loud optical drive

Tags: troubleshooting, optical-drive

At times, the Blu-ray drive in my computer will be very loud: it makes a grinding noise that I suspect is the drive motor. This is the computer equivalent of the sound a Honda Civic makes with an oversized tailpipe.

- This loud noise only occurs while reading discs, *not* writing.
- Sometimes it will make the loud noise for a short time when reading, then quiet down to almost nothing.
- This normally only happens when reading data discs, copying lots of files, creating MP4s, etc. and not watching a movie. I suspect the higher data rate requires the motor to spin faster which is part of the problem.
- I have a second drive in another computer with the exact same model number and it does *not* have this problem.
- Drive is an [LG BH10LS30](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-BH10LS30) that I have had in this (Windows 7 desktop) system for around two and a half years with regular usage.
- The drive functions perfectly fine. No defects when reading or writing discs, reads and writes at the rated speeds, no visual artifacts when watching Blu-ray or DVD movies. The only issue is the occasional noise.
- I removed the drive from the computer chassis and it appears to be intact with no visible or olfactory damage. If I gently shake it, I do not hear any loose parts rattling around.

**Is there anything I can do to mitigate the noise?** Given that I have had this drive for a few years and got good value out of it I accept the fact that sometime, possibly soon, I may have to replace it. But in the meantime if I can do something to get rid of the lawnmower noise a mere 16 inches from my head that would be great.

Comment: I have a standalone Bluray player that did the same thing.  While watching movies, it sounded like a lawnmower.  I was about to replace it, when a friend brought over a movie to watch.  The BluRay player was completely silent (not the movie!).  Since then, it hasn't been an issue.  So, for whatever reason, it just worked itself out.  I can't say the same will happen for you, but it's always possible.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard thing is it only does this some of the time, it comes and goes with the caveats I enumerated in my question. It has been doing this for a few months and does not seem to be going away. I will probably end up replacing the drive, the question is if there is anything I can do in the meantime. Sounds like "probably not."

Comment: Any correlation to WHICH discs are in it when it makes the noise?  Perhaps the center hub is a little off, and if a disc is not perfectly flat, it vibrates at high RPM.

Comment: @Snowman: I know of a machine that had a drive like that. The excess vibration finally caused a disc to shatter into smithereens inside and that was the end of the drive as well. If you value your discs then be aware of this possibility.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard no correlation to discs, only to what I am doing with those discs. Seems to be anything requiring high data rates that spin up the motor to max speed causes it.

Comment: In addition to what Karan mentioned, when a disc shatters it can send high-velocity shards all over the place.  How much do you trust the drive to keep those shards inside if that should happen?

Comment: I wouldn't know how, but have you tried spinning up the motor without a disk in the drive?  If it doesn't produce the noise then that's a strong indicator that your discs aren't perfectly centered when spinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same disks are quiet in one drive and not in the other, says the disks are OK.

The fact that it's only when actively using disks tells me the noise is the disk vibrating while rotating (possible because of higher RPMs while doing data reads vs. movie watching).

This tells me the drive hub is probably out of balance.

The easiest (and probably cheapest, and possibly only) repair is to simply replace the drive.

Current LG Super-Multi Blu Ray burner drives can be had for under $100 these days.